# Insect - Name of the insect

Tags: insects, butterflies

I clicked the picture of this insect near my plants. Can anyone help me in identifying this insect.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing where you are in the world would be useful, but this is likely one of the Hawk Moths; the one it most closely resembles is the Oleander Hawk Moth, which is a rare visitor to the UK - images variously display it as looking more brown or more green, but always with pinkish tinges, which I can't really tell are there in your photograph https://www.ukmoths.org.uk/species/daphnis-nerii/

Its larvae, or caterpillars, do feed on Oleander, but whether you would have the larvae in your country of residence isn't possible to say, since you don't say where you are.

UPDATE - I don't know if you've changed the image or tinkered with the original one, but whatever has happened, it makes the ID of Oleander Hawk Moth definite.

Comment: The pattern of the Oleander Hawk-moth in your link most certainly matches with this picture here.

Comment: oooh... the image is now much clearer and now the pink is much more obvious... definitely Oleander Hawk moth...

Comment: There was no change in the question - could it be that you did not have glasses the first time?

Comment: @VividD well you may not think anything has changed with the image, but I know it has - its better lit so the pink marking shows up, its not because of glasses or not. I have to say, although I imagine you're trying to be amusing, I bet you could start an argument in an empty room!

Comment: And you could sell air conditioners in Siberia! :)

Comment: @VividD If an answer is edited in a small timeframe after posting it (from my observations, a few minutes), the post will be shown as unedited and having the newest version. Try this next time you post an answer and see for yourself. As for the stingy comment with glasses, it reminds me of myself during adolescence. It's a low attitude to make fun of people's age, you know?

Comment: @Alina But at the same time, you approve bamboo lying about me creating tags with spelling errors, calling me ignorant, etc.?

Comment: Those are not lies, they are opinions that I have disagreed with in chat. Everyone has the right to an opinion just as I have the right to ignore it or to disagree with it.

Comment: @VividD - I did not use the word ignorant - that might be what you 'heard' but its not what I said. And the business of tag creation and my error in attributing that to you has already been apologised for, in public. I'm sorry if your ego is still smarting, but that's not my responsibility any more, its yours. I still think you were sort of joking with the glasses reference, but it doesn't matter much either way, to me anyway, life's too short for all this nonsense.

Comment: @Bamboo Yeah. Thanks for the answer. I currently live in India.

Comment: @Alina No, Bamboo said a series of lies about me, trying to paint me as bad as possible. Very immoral. I find her behavior very problematic. And, you have double standards. Too bad for you.

Comment: @KrishnaPS - In India, they breed, so if you've got any oleanders and they're nibbled, you know why!

Comment: @Bamboo Now i realize where this damage comes from ;)